# elasticsearch aggregation bucket sort order

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch

In elasticsearch, is there a way to sort/order the aggregation bucket using a custom score?

I am bucketing by customername. Each customer has several orders which has a delivery date field (delivdate). I want to sort the buckets based on the distance (closeness) to the current date.

For example sort the customername that has delivery date closer to today's date.

```
       "aggs": {
          "mygroup": {
             "terms": {
                "field": "customername",
                "order" : { "_term" : "asc" }
             }
           }
       }
```

Thank you

Comment: How many documents are there per customer. if there are many will all those documents have delivery date. If all those documents have delivery date  , then which one of these should be take for sorting ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately using a `scripted_metric`is not currently allowed for sorting an aggregation. Issue being tracked in: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/8486

Answer (score -1):

If you are using ElasticSearch v1.4.X, you could try to nest a [scripted metric](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-scripted-metric-aggregation.html) aggregation and use it to order your terms buckets.

```
"aggs": {
    "mygroup": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "customername",
        "order": {
          "custom_script": "asc"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "custom_script": {
          "scripted_metric": {
            ...
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Not tested, but theoritically, it should do the job.

Comment: Anyone try this?  I'm having trouble. Not sure that "scripted_metric" is allowed in this context.